# Is my Selenium Chrome Headless browser working as it should?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium, chromium

I am trying to make a connection to Google using Selenium with the headless parameter because I dont want a webbrowser to pop up.
And this is what I get
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLUUy.png)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadPage();
        }

        private static void LoadPage()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Dev\Documents\";
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();

            IWebDriver _driver;
            option.AddArgument("--headless");
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(path, option);
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://Google.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
```

How do I make sure I actually connecto to Google?

Comment: Read something from the page and output it?

Comment: @gilliduck So it does establisha  connection, whats the whole thing about only local connections..

Comment: Don't recall, but I believe that's normal. If this did the trick, I'll add this as an answer shortly for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), you have to disable GPU. Then you won't see that error. This is only temporarily workaround.

```
IWebDriver _driver;
option.AddArgument("--headless");
option.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
```

(I don't know the impact of disabling GPU)